# Two scrapy item loaders in a single parse method? how to merge them?

Tags: python, dictionary, xpath, scrapy, generator

I'm parsing a page but id like to divide it into sections, the page has info about multiple meetings. Some of the info is common to all meetings, but not everything. So i made an item loader for the general info and one for the specific info. However I'd like this parser to return all the info pertaining to a meeting (i.e: the general and specific). Here's the parse method of my code:

```
def parse(self, response):

    general_loader = ItemLoader(item=ProductItem(), response=response)
    general_loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    general_loader.default_output_processor = Join("  &  ")

    for field, xpath in self.general_item_fields.iteritems():
        general_loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)

    for meeting in response.xpath(self.meeting_xpath):
        specific_loader = ItemLoader(item=ProductItem(), response=meeting)
        specific_loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
        specific_loader.default_output_processor = Join("  &  ")

        for field, xpath in self.specific_item_fields.iteritems():
            specific_loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)
        yield general_loader.load_item().update(specific_loader.load_item())
```

The variables specific_item_fields and general_item_fields are dictionaries with the attribute of the meeting and it's xpath.

So what I'm trying to do here is use meeting as the response for a second ItemLoader that i called specific_loader. And since general_loader.load_item() seems to returns a dictionary, I tried updating or merging it with the specific_loader.load_item() dictionary.

Here's where I'm stuck:

- The update method is not working on the load_item and I can't seem to merge these two things.
- Apparently i can't use a response.xpath() (I'm using meeting here)element for the loader response?
- Finally there must be a better way to implement this, I've tried nested loaders and they seem very promising but meeting changes. It cycles through the response.xpath(self.meeting_xpath) list so how could i use nested loaders?

Thanks in advance for any pointers or advice, I'm kinda lost :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to actually merge two loaders into scrapy, but you could use the dictionaries created from them:

```
    ...
    general_item = general_loader.load_item()
    specific_item = specific_loader.load_item()

    general_item.update(specific_item)

    yield general_item
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It is what i was trying to do with that last line of code. Any other ideas?

Comment: why shouldn't it work? you are not doing the same in your code, you can't return (or yield) a `dict.update()`, because `update` doesn't return a dictionary, it only updates the current object.

Comment: Ohhhhhh i did not know 'update' changed the dictionary in place. Thank you @eLRuLL

Comment: my pleasure @MaxSmith